# Using Javascript/jQuery to get Query String in Segment-based URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using a PHP framework Codeigniter that uses segment based urls like `http://www.mydomain.com/age/11/name/john/color/red` instead of the usual querystrings lijke `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?age=11&name=john&color=red`.

**How do I grab the value of the `age`  key from the url using Javascript/jQuery?**

After grabbing the value `11` I will pass it into a jQuery object when an event is fired.

```
$( "#searchdistance_slider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 5,
        min: 0.5,
        max: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#search_distance" ).val(ui.value + " miles");
            window.location.replace("http://www.domain.com/" + age); 
            /* passing the value of age into URL to redirect to */
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

- The key/value pairs **can change position**, and the number of key/value pairs in the URL are not fixed
- I need to grab the value **within Javascript** because the user uses a slider to change a particular value, say the `age`, and the new value `20` from the slider will be use to redirect the user to `http://www.mydomain.com/age/20/name/john/color/red`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the [jQuery URL parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) plugin.

Use the `.segment(n)` call to search the URL path for `"age"`, and grab the next one which should contain the age value you're looking for.

Or try the `.fsegment(n)` method if `age` is always in the same position.

Or use `.segment()` with something like:

```
var parts = $.url(your_url).segment();
var params = [];
for (var i=0; i<parts.length/2; i++) {
   params[parts[2*i]] = parts[2*i+1];
}
var age = parseInt(params['age']);
```

(I'm sure there's a prettier way to do that though.)

If you only want the `age` part, you don't have to do all that stuffing into a dictionary. Just exit the loop early when you've found the key you want.

If you want to reconstruct the path with a changed age, try something like:

```
var parts = $.url(your_url).segment();
var newpath = '';
for (var i=0; i<parts.length/2; i++) {
  if (parts[2*i] == 'age') {
    newpath += '/age/' + (parseInt(parts[2*i+1]) + 42); // put your age modifiy
                                                        // code here
  } else {
    newpath += '/' + parts[2*i] + '/' + parts[2*i+1];
  }
}
alert(newpath);
```

Comment: the position of the key/value pair in the url segments changes, so I think its hard to target a particular key/value pair easily using the plugin from what I can see

Comment: Not really. `.segment()` returns an array of all the path fragments. Just hash that if you need key-based lookup (I'll post an example).

Comment: great.. do you know of a quick way to reconstruct the entire url after updating `params['age']`? I'm thinking along the lines of using a similar `for` loop to the one used to hash the array, but with `newurl += newurl + "/" + parts[2*i] + "/" + parts[2*i+1]` occurring with each iteration

Comment: updated. Note that the new path does not contain the scheme + domain name, you'll need to add that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could split it with something like this:

```
var parts = {},
    bits = location.pathname.substr(1).split('/'); // get rid of first / and split on slashes

for (var i = 0; i<bits.length; i += 2) {
    parts[bits[i]] = bits[i+1];
}
```

You could then access the `age` value with `parts.age`.

Comment: Sounds like this will work. I have updated my question. How do I update the value of `age` with a new value, then pass the url with the new value of `age` to `window.location.replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

before your code is run, add the following to your php script:

```
<?php
$getAgre = ( isset($_GET['age']) && strlen($_GET['age'])>0 )? $_GET['age'] : 'null';
echo '<script>var age = '. $getAge .';</script>';
?>
```

edit: make sure you have some security checking before displaying the content of $_GET['age'] and your JS would be better when your event in **.slider()** checked whether variable **get** exists

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.href` variable which would give you the whole current url, and then play with the string a bit to get the desired information. Substring, split, even regex.

This would work:

```
var ageMatch= window.location.href.match(/age\/([\d]*)/);
var age= ageMatch[1];
```

Just for the record, you can also update the url just as easily:

```
var newUrl= window.location.href.replace(/age\/([\d]*)/, age);
window.location.href= newUrl;
```